# How helpful can PyMesh be in identifying flat surfaces and centroids on those flat surfaces?

Tags: python-3.x, mesh

[Image of Surfaces](https://i.stack.imgur.com/COeNW.png)

In the picture, two flat surfaces of interest are shown in white: FlatSurface1 and FlatSurface2. Would PyMesh be helpful in helping me identify the flat surfaces on my 3D mesh models? And on those flat surfaces, would PyMesh be able to find the centroids of those flat surfaces? For example, in the picture I placed one red centroid dot for Surface1, and 4 centroid dots on Surface2.

I'd greatly appreciate any helpful information, or recommendations for other ways to work with mesh files for my needs.